# Screen flashing for front camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I tried to create screen flashing front camera app, but i am not able to done this. here is my code please help to complete this.

- i used camera2 api for camera activity
- Created new activity for screen flashing
- Intented from camera activity but its not working properly 
  please give me solution for that

Camera2Fragment.java

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.picture: {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(),SplashActivity.class),1);
                    takePicture();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.info: {
                        Activity activity = getActivity();
                        if (null != activity) {
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                                        .setMessage(" This sample demonstrates the basic use of Camera2" +
                                                " API. Check the source code to see how  you can display camera preview and take pictures.")
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                                        .show();
                        }
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        h=new Handler();
        cResolver=getContentResolver();
        changeBright=255;
        window = getWindow();
//if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity, Manifest.permission.SETT))
 Settings.System.putInt(cResolver,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,changeBright);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layourPars=window.getAttributes();
        layourPars.screenBrightness=changeBright/(float)255;``
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Intent openMain = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                openMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(openMain);

            }
        }, 1000);
        SplashActivity.this.setResult(1);
    }

}
```